# The file locking program is NOT LOCKING FILES

Tags: c, file-locking, fcntl

I have made a program to have advisory file locking in the c program and below is the code I have written for the task.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


int controller, fsize;
char data[1000], ch;
int fd ;
                  /* l_type, l_whence, l_start, l_len, l_pid*/
struct flock fl = {F_UNLCK, SEEK_SET,    0,       0,      0};
void Edit();
void Delete();
void Exit();
void Lock();


void main()
{

do
{
    clrscr();
    fd = open("demo.txt", "w");
    FILE *fp = fdopen("demo.txt", "w");
    if (fd != NULL)
    {
        printf("Opening the file!\n");
        fd = fdopen("demo.txt", "r");
        printf("We can open the file in write mode, meaning no other process has lock enabled on it.");
        printf("Contents of the file are: \n\t");
        readfile(fd);
        fclose(fd);
    }
    else if ((fd = fopen("demo.txt", "r"))!= NULL)
    {
        fd = fopen("demo.txt", "r");
        printf("We can open the file in read mode, meaning some other process has locked the write permissions on it.");
        printf("Contents of the file are: \n\t");
        readfile(fd);
        fclose(fd);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File does not exist.\n");
    }
    printf("\n\t\t***** WELCOME USER! THIS IS A SIMPLE TEXT EDITOR *****");

    Lock();
    Operations();
}
while(1);
}

void Lock()
{
fd = fopen("demo.txt", "w");
fl.l_type = F_RDLCK;
fl.l_pid = getpid();
if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl) == -1)
{
    printf("Can't set exclusive lock\n");
}
else if(fl.l_type!=F_UNLCK)
{
    printf("File has been exclusively locked by the process %d\n", fl.l_pid);
    fl.l_type = F_UNLCK;
    printf("File Unlocked! Other processes can execute on the file now.");
}
else
{
    printf("File is not locked\n");
}
fclose(fd);
}

void clrscr()
{
system("@cls||clear");
}

void Operations()
{
    printf("\n\n\tOperations you can perform here:\n\t\n");
    printf("\n\t1.ADD TO FILE\n\t2.DELETE THE FILE\n\t3.EXIT\n");
    printf("\n\tEnter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&controller);
    switch(controller)
    {
    case 1:
        Add();
        break;
    case 2:
        remove("demo.txt");
        break;
    case 3:
        exit(0);
    }
}



void Add()
{
    fd = fopen("demo.txt", "a");
    printf("Enter contents to store in file : \n");
    fgets(data, 1000, stdin);
    fputs(data, fd);
    fclose(fd);
    printf("Data added to the file successfully");
    fd = fopen("demo.txt", "r");
    readfile(fd);
    fclose(fd);
}



void readfile(FILE *fPtr)
{
char c = getc(fd);
while (c != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", c);
    c = getc(fd);
}
}
```

The program is made such that it issues advisory locking whenever there is another attempt to open that particular file in another process. The new user(from new process) can then however edit the file.

But the program is not working properly. Can anyone please help me find the error in the code. I am not able to identify what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: You get a lock, but release it a split second later (`fclose(fd);`)

Comment: I m having trouble in opening and losing the file. Where should I open the file and where should I close it? I guess im supposed to have a file lock for the entire length of the program execution. Or atleast have it until the process process requests the switch

Comment: Then close the file just as you are about to exit (or not at all and let the OS close it automatically as the program exits).

Comment: You seem to have created a new user account in order to again ask a [previously closed question]() without addressing any of the issues which caused the question to be closed. I don't think that's particularly helpful. You should also attempt to understand the issues identified in comments to your previous attempt, including the confusion between file descriptors (`int`s) and standard library  `FILE*`. If you compiled with warnings enabled, the compiler would produce warning messages, too.

Comment: --> [previously closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65367005/file-locking-in-the-program-is-not-locking-files)

Comment: desperate times, desperate measures sir @ rici . and what about the opening of the file kind sir? @ikegami should I just open it once at the starting of the program?

Comment: If that's when you want to lock it

Comment: so I don't need to keep opening and closing it in every other function?

Comment: Those sorts of "desperate measures" are how people get banned.

Comment: hahaha... yes sir you're right.. But do you know 'tempmail' always shows a new mail ID every time you open it. What a great fact, right? haha.. I am just kidding here. I really hate people spamming this website, but I am a novice coder with deadlines on my head

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxxxxxx Do not abuse this site.  Instead, put your effort into writing a good question and address the comments people write.  Questions get closed due to lack of effort, not because people help you.  If your question gets closed, address the reason why it was closed and it'll be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Does that program even compile? Advisory locks are only advisory, they don't prevent other processes from opening the files, or do read/write. They only tell you when it is *safe* to use the file descriptors. So the way to use them, is to only do read/write when you actually *have* the lock.

The meaning of "safe" in this context cannot have a generic answer, it depends on use case. But typically implies that the programmer(s) have ensured that the file is in a consistent state before acquisition and after release of the lock.

Comment: I am using windows on my laptop and doing this for a client who needs the program to be working in linux. So I used fcntl(because it is supported in linux, and if I used win32.. it would have been of no use for the client). I could not test  the code myself and I know it has errors(because of my track records with codes) so I just need to know what are the things that im doing wrong "this time" and hopefully fix it before submission to the client

Comment: how should I implement advisory locking sir? I even tried searching the web for an answer but wasn't able to find one. Can you atleast guide me in the right direction?

Comment: The right direction is to first learn about the difference between file streams and low level file descriptors, and also learn how to compile with `-Wall`. Then, locking is probably better done with `flock` function. When and how to use it depends on your use case. Typically you have to identify what is your atomic operations and lock around that. This needs the ability to write clean code. I cannot show how to do the locking based on your code since it is to messy. It needs mayor cleanup first. Sorry, I know this sounds elitist, but you need to build programming experience in the right order.